# Where is stored MongoDB's data wtih SailsJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I wonder where MongoDB's datas are stored.
Indeed, I'm using Sailsjs 0.9.9 framework based on nodejs and I've turn on mongodb as default database like explained :
- I've commented the config/adapter.js and added these lines into config/local.js :

```
adapters: {
'default': 'mongo',
mongo: {
  module: 'sails-mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'mymongodb',

  schema: true
}
```

}

Of course, i've installed sails-mongo module with npm.

In my webpages generated with Sailsjs, no troubles I've my datas. But when i go into my shell and I try to get datas stored in my sailsjs apps, the database is empty...

```
[myuser@localhost myApp]$ mongo mymongodb
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: mymongodb
> db.mymongodb.find()
>
```

As you can see, nothing is returned by this command, and I wonder why...

Could you help me ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.mymongodb.find()` tries to list documents from a collection called `mymongodb` within a database called `mymongodb`. Probably, there's no such collection, that's why the query is empty.

Now, if you want to see the data, you should type `show collections`, then

```
db.<collectionName>.find()
```

where `<collectionName>` would probably correspond to the name of one of your models.

Comment: You perfectly answered my problem. I mixed differents notions. Thanks a lot it's pretty cleared now !